# Get image by GeoJSON from Sentinelsat

Tags: python, sentinel-2, sentinelsat

I have a polygon geometry file. Upon request

```
footprint = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson('C:\\Users\\kurma\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\geojsons\\file_5.geojson'))
products = api.query(footprint,
                 date=('NOW-1DAY', 'NOW' ),
                 platformname='Sentinel-2',
                 producttype = 'S2MSI2A',
                 cloudcoverpercentage=(0, 30))
api.download_all(products)
```

I get the whole tile. Can I download only the area I need, which is much smaller than the tile?

Comment: What is `api`? `footprint` is a polygon WKT string, right? Could you provide some additional information of the objects you are using?

Comment: api is sentinelsat API. Yes, you got it right,  footprint is a polygon WKT string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to download only your area of interest, only the full sized tile. What you can do is limit your download to bands you are interested in, but not the size of the tile.

This is due to the way `sentinelsat` interacts with the API of the Copernicus Open Access Hub. The Copernicus Hub itself only delivers full-sized images and the functionality of `sentinelsat` provides a Python interface to that API.